# Django Crispy forms not using bootstrap 4 to build Accordion

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I'm using crispy-forms app for django to bootstrap forms. I'm using bootstrap 4 have no problems when just using the {form|crispy} output but now I want to add an accordion and crispy is generating the HTML for bootstrap 3 instead of 4.

I've included in the settings.py the line:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

My view.py looks like this:

```
from app.models import Model1

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import Accordion, AccordionGroup

class Model1Create(CreateView):
   model = Model1
   fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
   template_name = "model1_form.html"

   def get_form(self, form_class=None):
       form = super().get_form(form_class)
       form.helper = FormHelper()
       form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Creates', css_class='btn-primary'))

       form.helper.layout = Layout(
            Accordion(
                AccordionGroup('First Group',
                    'field1'
                ),
                AccordionGroup('Second Group',
                    'field2',
                    'field3'
                )
            ))

       return form
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Or what should I do to force bootstrap 4 html?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on implementing an accordion group as well.  The first hurdle I needed to overcome (I'm stuck on a new problem now :) ) was to ensure:

"Accordion & AccordionGroup: AccordionGroup renders an accordion pane, different groups need to be wrapped in an Accordion for automatic javascript functioning, also you will need **bootstrap-tab.js** included in your static files:"

I saw that line in the documentation which you can find here:

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html?highlight=accordion

Does that help?